# Arcgis Dynamic Mapservice from sqlserver 2008 r2

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, map-service

I publish the mapservices from the sqlserver2008 R2 through ArcSDE using ArcServer 10.1. 
Its fine i published, now i change the attributes of my existing gdb using ArcSDE.
Now the updated information is not replicated in the mapservices.  How can i solve the issue.

Comment: How do you change your attributes and how do you verify that the updated information is not available in a map service (a web app? just adding a map service to ArcMap? etc)

Comment: change the attributes value in my Enterprise database SQLServer 2008 R2 using ArcSDE. Then refresh the Mapservices from the web app, its not reflect the changes. need the proper procedure to do this task..may be i am wrong

Comment: It is still unclear what data you are editing (feature classes, tables), how you edit it (you cannot use ArcSDE to edit data, it is just a gateway - you use ArcMap GUI or SQL statements), how do you verify that the data was edited and saved, how do you access the map service in web application.

Comment: Yes, Using ArcMap i have edited the tables and saved. 
After Edit i saved and able to verity the updated field.
Already i published the mapservices.
Now i refreshed again in my web mapping application application it not showing any updated in the feature information Window.

Comment: Good. 1. Can you check whether when you have published a map service the data was not copied to the server (if you don't properly set up the data store)? If yes, then the map service and your ArcSDE geodatabase will no connection whatsoever. A good way to check this is to create/delete a new feature and then check if it visible/non-existing in the web app. 2. If the map service and the geodatabase are still connected, then try to delete the web browser cache and restart the application.

Answer (score 1):

The issues is with the OS itself and the way that files work with ArcGIS.

You are running two applications.  Two applications can have trouble reading the same file.  The interface to edit the file and the web application itself.  Since the web application can still function the file while editing either SDE is likely caching the results until you close the client or the web server is running completely off cache until it read the file again.  When you save your work the interface is still likely to be holding a lock of some sort or not publishing.

Close your client.  Wait a few seconds and check for results.

Answer (score 1):

Potentials issues I can think of...

- You didn't setup the data store on AGS and a copy of the database was created to support the map service (as stated by Alex Tereshenkov)
- You are editing the wrong version of geodatabase (unlikely but you never know)
- You didn't clear the ArcGIS Services Directory cache (see this [blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/10/08/clearing-the-arcgis-services-directory-cache-the-easy-way/) for details)